# Find and click on a element using selenium,python

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

I am trying to automatically add this blue Jbl speaker in the cart so there are the steps first go to [link of the Jbl speaker](https://www.amazon.in/dp/B010RWAIAC/ref=twister_B07D5KL6TC?_encoding=UTF8&th=1) and click on click on blue jbl speaker and click on add to cart button

But I can't reach to the Url saying error This site cant be reached

Comment: there been a cookies issue or internet problem

Comment: Please provide your code and the error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please read [ask], especially the part about [mcve] (MCVE), and [How much research effort is expected?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592/how-much-research-effort-is-expected-of-stack-overflow-users) This will help you debug your own programs and solve problems for yourself. If you do this and are still stuck you can come back and post your MCVE, what you tried, and the execution result including any error messages so we can better help you. Also provide a link to the page and/or the relevant HTML.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

There been a cookies issue try it

```html
from selenium import webdriver
import time
driver = webdriver.Chrome(executable_path = "PATH OF CHROMEDRIVER")
driver.maximize_window()
driver.get("http://https://www.amazon.in")
driver.get("https://www.amazon.in/dp/B010RWAIAC/ref=twister_B07D5KL6TC?_encoding=UTF8&th=1")
time.sleep(5)
driver.find_element_by_id('color_name_1_price').click()
time.sleep(3)
driver.find_element_by_id('add-to-cart-button').click()
```